# Why a rust immutable reference can call &mut self methd?

Tags: rust

Why a rust immutable reference can call &mut self methd?

in my code comments:

1. stdin's type is &ChildStdin, why can call a "&mut self" function write_all?
2. and why as_ref result can call a "&mut self" function write_all?

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let child = Command::new("cmd.exe")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;

    let mut stdin = child.stdin.as_ref().unwrap();
    
    //1. stdin's type is &ChildStdin, why can call a "&mut self" function write_all?
    stdin.write_all(b"dir\n")?;

    //2. and why as_ref result can call a "&mut self" function write_all?
    child.stdin.as_ref().unwrap().write_all(b"dir\n")?;
 
    let output = child.wait_with_output()?;

    println!("output = {:?}", output);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: cause write is also implemented for `&ChildStdin` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ChildStdin.html#impl-Write-1 so `&mut self` == `&mut &ChildStdin`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the documentation of `ChildStdin`, you can find the [`impl Write for &ChildStdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ChildStdin.html#impl-Write-1). This was added in 1.48 because these writes are supposedly safe to call, according to [the original issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/73836):

> The implementations of Write which are MT-safe under the covers can implement a trait along the lines of [...] and some already do [...].
> However, these appear to be the extent of the current implementations. The following types could also do the same:
>
> - [...]
> - ChildStdin – similar to File or *Streams;

and the [PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/76275/).

---

Notably, we don't have a `&mut ChildStdin` at any point. Instead, you create a mutable reference *to the immutable reference*, a `&mut &ChildStdin`. This mutable reference is then given to the `write_all` trait method from the linked `Write` implementation for `&ChildStdin`.

While there is a `impl Write for ChildStdin` too (which would need a `&mut ChildStdin`), we don't actually use it here.